# Spellchecker confused in Chrome (using Outlook webApp email)

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, spell-check

For some reason Outlook webApp running in Chrome objects to the spelling of week (7 days) in the message below.

Any ideas if this is an outlook issue or a Chrome issue? (Edit looks like a Chrome issue - see below)

It also appears to be an intermittent issue that came up unexpectedly and other instances of week and weeks in the same message were not highlighted.

[image]

---

Edit - looks like a Chrome issue below is an image from writing out this message, which shows some instances of week highlighted and another not highlighted...

--

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser? Clearing your cache?

Comment: @music2myear, thanks for the comment - I have updated the question - looks like a browser issue - ok I could try to clear the cache... -- or use Firefox, which seems to be unwilling to highlight spelling mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OWA 2010 and previous version, there was an option to check the spelling of the message upon sending. Since OWA 2013, OWA completely relies on the spell check capabilities of the browser. You may right-click on 'week' and see what auto-correct suggestion it lists. You can also click 'Add to dictionary' to see whether it helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I really appreciate it.